# CPU cores and sys.dm_os_workers

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017

We recently failed over our AOAG cluster to a secondary region.  In the first region, our boxes had 32 cores while in the secondary region, we have 64 cores.  Traffic is similar, however on the larger boxes we're running much higher numbers of workers in sys.dm_os_workers (and also threads in sys.dm_os_threads).  Is this expected behavior when raising CPU cores or should we be concerned about all these idle workers?

We're running SQL Server 2017 CU 24.

`max worker threads` is configured to `0` (the default value).

`max degree of parallelism` is configured to `2` in both regions.

In the current server, we're seeing the following counts:

| session_count | request_count | worker_count | thread_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2366 | 389 | 1172 | 1265 |

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What I'm really trying to answer is should the number of workers increase dramatically when we increase the number of CPUs?

> Traffic is similar, however on the larger boxes we're running much higher numbers of workers in sys.dm_os_workers (and also threads in sys.dm_os_threads).

Without going into the minutia, the number of cores has little bearing on the number of workers or threads in the process for a server under normal load.

The use of threads falls into three different buckets, the first being threads that are needed to run long lived permanent tasks in a preemptive mode such as the lease in an AG setup, CLR hosting, etc., or 3rd party module items such as driver providers. The second bucket are long lived permanent tasks that are SQL related, such as scheduler manager, lazywriter, and other SQL-bootstrapped items which tend to be partitioned by *numa node* and not by number of cores. The third bucket are SQL query execution related items such as satisfying queries or logins.

Workers fall into the same buckets except for the first as there aren't worker constructs associated with those types of threads (Examples below).

While you'll have more threads and workers due to the first two buckets assuming there are more numa nodes, it shouldn't be dramatic unless the number of threads and workers was already low. The main difference will be in where the work is assigned. Since each scheduler will have certain local queues and work being spread across more schedulers, there will be more workers and threads as even having one extra scheduler will require one more thread and worker.

Normal server activity will spin up and down workers and threads as needed. Periodic spikes in workload or scheduling changes can make this effect seem larger than otherwise expected but is normal.

Overall, though, this is nothing to worry about unless you're hitting max worker threads - in which case changing the value to something else would not be the appropriate course of action as a solution.

Example - Bucket 1: Long lived Non-SQL permanent

```
sqlservr!DCOMInitThread
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart
```

Example - Bucket 2: Long lived SQL Bootstrapped

```
sqlmin!lazywriter
sqldk!SOS_Task::Param::Execute
sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::RunTask
sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::ProcessTasks
sqldk!SchedulerManager::WorkerEntryPoint
sqldk!SystemThread::RunWorker
sqldk!SystemThreadDispatcher::ProcessWorker
sqldk!SchedulerManager::ThreadEntryPoint
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart
```

Example - Bucket 3: Regular SQL User Workerload

```
sqllang!CXStmtSelect::XretExecute
sqllang!CExecStmtLoopVars::ExecuteXStmtAndSetXretReturn
sqllang!CMsqlExecContext::ExecuteStmts<1,0>
sqllang!CMsqlExecContext::FExecute
sqllang!CSQLSource::Execute
sqllang!process_request
sqllang!process_commands_internal
sqllang!process_messages
sqldk!SOS_Task::Param::Execute
sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::RunTask
sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::ProcessTasks
sqldk!SchedulerManager::WorkerEntryPoint
sqldk!SystemThread::RunWorker
sqldk!SystemThreadDispatcher::ProcessWorker
sqldk!SchedulerManager::ThreadEntryPoint
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart
```

Comment: @JamesSpruiell - The number of numa nodes impacts permanent sql items, so I'd extra 2-4 threads extra per numa node assuming no traceflags. The item that's playing into the main part of the increase is that each scheduler will have at least 1 thread associated with it at all times, so going form 32->64 you'll have a net 32 added. If you went from 2 numa nodes to 8, there'd be another ~24 threads. Additionally only certain items kick in with number of cores hitting a minimum, such as hekaton, log writers, etc. It's a very in-depth topic that would require its own section but the gist is above.

Answer (score 5):

With over 2300 sessions, it's quite likely that the server was seeing a lot of `threadpool` waits when running in the prior region.

By default, SQL Server configures the maximum number of worker threads based on the number of cores available.  See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-worker-threads-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15#Recommendations) for details, but suffice it to say these are the default values for SQL Server 2017:

| Number of CPUs | 64-bit computer (starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x) SP2 and SQL Server 2017 (14.x)) |
| --- | --- |
| <= 4 | 512 |
| 8 | 576 |
| 16 | 704 |
| 32 | 960 |
| 64 | 1472 |
| 128 | 4480 |
| 256 | 8576 |

As you can see, going from 32 cores to 64 cores bumps up the max worker threads from 960 to 1472.  Depending on how busy your server actually is, you may want to bump the number of threads up from the default values.  Look at [Erik Darling's sp_PressureDetector proc](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sp_pressuredetector/) for details on what's going on with your threads.